# How to generate k largest subset sums for a given array (contains positive and negative numbers)

Tags: algorithm

So the question is pretty straight forward, given an array of size N( N<=10^5) , we want to generate k greatest subset sums where k is in worst case MIN of (2000 and 2^N).

We have to output in the decreasing order.

Is there any way to do this in less than exponential complexity.
My thinking is that
If we have to generate 2^N items , how can the complexity be less than 2^N,

Asked in amazon OA(question is called find k maximum priority)

Comment: The obvious answer is that you don't have to generate all 2^N items.  For example, you can find the greatest subset sum by making a single pass through the array (that is, O(N)).

Comment: Its min of (2000,2^N) because 2^N is the cap of number of subsets array can have. So complexity is not going to be 2^N

Comment: I get this method but I have some doubts. We will just take the sum of all the positive elements , then we will have the choice of removing the smallest positive element or adding the smallest negative number to get the next sum, so in order to do this we can just store the Math.abs of all the numbers in a min heap, and subtract the output of the min heap from the maxSum to get the next greatest sum. But will this be enough, as with this method we will only be able to generate N+1 sums right. I just rechecked the constraints , it is k<2^n . So is my method wrong or will k always be <=N+1

Comment: If your method can only produce N+1 sums, and k>N+1, you lose.

Comment: @BosssMan861 Were you able to clear the OA round, as you didn't gave the optimized approach?

Comment: @CoderGuyy The top answer actually passes all the test cases. I had almost all the OA questions before hand ( from discord and telegram where other people were taking the OA) , only this one I wasn't able to solve and guess what I got this same question on the OA, I managed to pass all test cases for both questions , but I have seen candidates who pass one question fully and 2nd question partially ( like 11/19) and still get the interview call.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'll just outline it.  It is up to you to implement it and show that it works.

First, in a single pass, we find the sum of the positive numbers.  This is the maximum sum.  We initialize our answer array with `[maximum_sum]`.

Next, we create an array `av` of the absolute values, sorted from smallest to largest.

Next, we create a priority queue `upcoming`.  It will start with one pair in it.  That pair will be `(maximum_sum - av[0], 0)`.  The pairs are compared lexicographically with largest sum first.

Until we have enough elements in `answer` we will:

```
get (next_sum, i) from upcoming
add next_sum to answer
if i < N:
    add (next_sum + av[i] - av[i+1], i+1) to upcoming
    add (next_sum - av[i+1], i+1) to upcoming
```

This algorithm will take `O(N+k)` memory and `O(N log(N) + k log(k))` work to generate the top `k` answers.  It depends on both `N` and `k` but is exponential in neither.

Comment: Here is the implementation https://leetcode.com/playground/Gm2v6aee

Comment: Wow how did you come up with this

Comment: So we take the current maxSum, see which element was removed to form the current maxSum , we then make the choice to add back the i th element or not. You are a genius my friend .  How did you derive this from the 2^n recursive approach, wanna know your thought process

Comment: @BosssMan861 I've just done a lot of these.

Comment: Here you can test your implementation: https://leetcode.com/contest/weekly-contest-307/problems/find-the-k-sum-of-an-array/

Answer (score 1):

I will describe a bit simpler solution:

Let `A` be initial array, let `Pos` and `Neg` be sets of all positive (nonnegative, to be exact) and all negative numbers from `A` respectively.

Let us look at the problem from another point of view. Instead of choosing subsets from `A`
and minimizing sums of both positive and negative numbers, we will consider an equivalent problem:

Take `MaxSum` := sum of all numbers in `Pos`. Clearly, this is the biggest possible sum we can get.
Starting from `MaxSum`, we can get any subset sum of `A` by adding some numbers from `Neg` and subtracting some numbers from `Pos`. Note, that both operations subtract some **nonnegative** value from `MaxSum`! Thus, we’ve reduced our problem to a simpler one:

**Simpler Problem:**
Take `Abs` :=  set of absolute values of `Pos` and `Neg` (<=> set of all absolute values of `A`).
We need to choose `k` smallest sums from `Abs` **to subtract from** `MaxSum`.

**Solution:**
Take smallest `m`, such that `2^m >= min(2^N, k)`. By the constrains of the problem we have `m <= 11`.
Obviously, `k` smallest sums from `Abs` are some subsets of the smallest `m` numbers of `Abs`.
Thus, we can consider all such `2^m <= 2048` subsets and get smallest sums
`(s_1, s_2, ... s_k)`. The final answer will be `(MaxSum - s_1, MaxSum - s_2, ... MaxSum - s_k)`.

**Time complexity:**

1. `O(N)` to find `MaxSum`
2. `O(N log(N))`, for example, to find `m` smallest numbers from `Abs`. In fact, finding `m` smallest numbers can be done with `O(N + m log(m))` complexity, see [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/k-largestor-smallest-elements-in-an-array/). Since `m <= 11`, we can say that time complexity is also `O(N)`.
3. `O(1)` to consider `2^m <= 2048` sums from `m` numbers (using bit masks, for example).

**Total time complexity:** `O(Nlog(N))` for straightforward approach and `O(N)` for optimized approach.

**Space complexity:** `O(N + k)` (<=> `O(N)`, since `k <= 2000`).